# What is the second parameter for in the woocommerce_account_menu_items filter?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wherever I see the woocommerce_account_menu_items filter used to reorder the woo commerce my accounts page endpoint links I see something like this.

```
function wpb_woo_my_account_order() {
$myorder = array(
    'dashboard'          => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
    'orders'             => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
    'subscriptions'      => __( 'Subscriptions', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-address'       => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
    'payment-methods'    => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-account'       => __( 'Account Details', 'woocommerce' ),
    'customer-logout'    => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
);
return $myorder;
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'wpb_woo_my_account_order' );
```

take for example

```
'payment-methods'    => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
```

What is the "woocommerce" second part for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `__()` makes it possible for you translate strings in different languages.

- The first parameter is simply a string which should be available for
  translation
- The second parameter is the **unique text domain** which is optional. Giving the
  function a second parameter makes sense, just to make sure the string
  is reserved by your theme or your plugin. Actually you can call it
  whatever you like. The default value is `default`.

So in your case the string `Payment Methods` is reserved by `woocomerce`. But you can add your own translations like `__( 'Payment Methods', 'my-plugin' )`. That way the value will be different.

In order to translate strings, you will need to work with .mo and .po files. [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) will help you manage those files.

Check this page for more information about `__()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/